# How can I execute a stored procedure whose name is in a variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given a variable that contains a stored procedure name:

```
DECLARE @stored_procedure_name varchar(512);
SET @stored_procedure_name = 'some_stored_procedure_name';
```

How can I execute the stored procedure (without passing in any arguments)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the variable *directly*:

```
exec @stored_procedure_name;
```

Please see the [BOL Reference on `EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

A procedure name is an identifier name in SQL Server, and it follows the rules of the [database identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
For object names I prefer to use the special data type [sysname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (a synonym for NVARCHAR(128)).

In order to execute it you'd need to use dynamic SQL using [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or system procedure [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

PS: see @ThomasStringer's example on an execution.

PS2: if later you'll need to add parameters, the best way to do that is to execute with sp_executesql.